# How to modify the HTML formatting of an oEmbed link?

Tags: oembed

I am trying to add oEmbed DeviantArt integration to a custom theme.

I found that first step is quite easy, I added

```
wp_oembed_add_provider( 'http://*.deviantart.com/#/d*', 'http://backend.deviantart.com/oembed' );
```

to theme's *functions.php*.

Now, I would like to change the default HTML output to add more information, available in DeviantArt JSON response ([DeviantART reference](http://dt.deviantart.com/blog/35616831/)), like author_name, author_url, etc.

If I have studied well the WP code that manage the output is inside function *data2html* in *class-oembed.php*, but I don't like change the code here.

How can I add a function to my theme, to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WP_oEmbed::data2html()` has a filter, [`oembed_dataparse`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L262). You can use this to change the output, based on the extra data which is passed as the second parameter.

Something like this for example:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', 'wpse17461_oembed_dataparse', 10, 3 );
function wpse17461_oembed_dataparse( $html, $data, $url )
{
    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $url, 'deviantart.com' ) ) {
        return $html . '<br/>Author: ' . $data->author_name;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a note, your code generate an error, maybe causes by my environment. I fixed it using: **return $html . '<br/>Author: ' . $data->author_name;**

Comment: @Drake: Ah, indeed, I did not test it, so I did not know whether `$data` was an array or an object. I corrected it, thanks.